# Service in background Windows Phone

Tags: service, windows-phone-7.1

Is there something in Windows Phone similar to services in Android? 
I already read the documentation on Background agents (Periodic agents) but they only perform some code once every 30 minutes.

I need to have a service running all the time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in 7.1 it is not possible. I hope in the next versions this will change.